# Patch two files with one diff

Tags: git

I've got two files: config.yml-sample and config.yml. The first one is being constantly updated, while the second is listed in .gitignore. When I add a line in config.yml-sample and push the commit, I want to have it duplicated in config.yml automatically on pull at other developers' workspaces.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove `config.yml` from `.gitignore`, or use a [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to update the file from `config.yml-sample`. It seems to me that a `post-checkout` hook would be appropriate.

Comment: You might actually want to run this from `post-merge` and `post-commit` too.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple option is to have your application read `config.yml.sample` on startup to find all the configuration keys (or whatever) that are mentioned there.  Then after loading `config.yml` you can see if any of those required keys are missing, and prompt the user to copy those lines in from `config.yml.sample`, possibly customizing them when doing so.